# Loop through a list of values of a specific record

Tags: angularjs

I have the following database:

```
{
  "games" : [ {
    "event" : [ "Event 1", "Event 2", "Event 3" ],
    "name" : "Game 1"
  }, {
    "event" : [ "Event 1", "Event 2", "Event 3" ],
    "name" : "Game 2"
  } ]
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to loop through all events for a specific game using attributes with angularjs.  Here is an example:

Here I loop through all the games and print out buttons with each game. Then if you click on the button it makes the game become active:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 noPadding" ng-repeat="game in data.games">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button 
                type="button" 
                class="btn largeButton" 
                ng-class="{'btn-success':game==data.game,'btn-danger':gameType!=data.game}" 
                ng-click="data.child('game').set(game);">
                {{game}}
            </button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now next I need to loop through all the events and print out the buttons for that game, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this through attributes.

```
<div ng-repeat="event in data.games.where(game:game.name == 'Game 1').events">
```

Is something as what I wrote above possible?

I'm rather new with angularjs. I was looking at using `| filter` but I can't seem to figure out how to do the expression.

Comment: Indeed, you need to use filter. Create jsfiddle to have something to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is looping on the `game` element from your first loop and accessing the `game.event` array with dot notation. The ng-if statement can check if the current array element `(game.event[i])` is your current game. If that ng-if statement fails, all AngularJS code after the first div will not execute, and no buttons will be made.

I'm using `currentGame` to avoid variable name collisions as a $scope variable that stores the name of the currently selected game: presumably set in your data.child('game').set(game) function when the user selects a game to play in your previously supplied code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 noPadding" 
  ng-repeat="game in data.games" 
  ng-if="currentGame = game.name">
     <div ng-repeat="eventElement in game.event">
         <button id="{{eventElement}}-button" 
          class='btn primary' 
          ng-click="startGame(eventElement)">{{eventElement}}</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this answers your question and makes sense. :)